# Not able to access obejct property in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access `javascript object property`.

```
const one = data[acti][0]?.Original?.Form.sortorder
```

So here it is saying that sortorder is not avaliable on that object.

when I logged  `data[acti][0]?.Original?.Form` then the Form object has following values,

```
Form = {
  id: '1',
  sortorder: 0
}
```

So, I am confused why I am not able to access that.

If I try to use it like

```
data[acti][0]?.Original?.Form['sortorder']
```

then I am able to access.

Can any one help me figure out this ?

```js
var Form = {
  id: '1',
  sortorder: 0
}

console.log( Form.sortorder )
console.log( Form['sortorder'] )
```

Getting this error

Property 'sortorder' does not exist on type 'testNode'.ts(2339)

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Is this a TypeScript error? Post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Form` object must match your TypeScript type definition

Obviously you didn't mention `sortorder` to be a property of the "testNode" type.